# it doesn't read the string and it still outputs from the catch. how do i get it to read the "q" and quit it

Tags: java

```
do {
    try {
        System.out.println("how many times");

        stringy = scanner.next();
        rollnumber = Integer.parseInt(stringy);

        if (stringy.equals("q")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        nigh = 2;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("invalid. re-enter");
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
} while (nigh == 1);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Its supposed to read the string but it still obviously doesn't register it in the system.exit. Please explain to me and examples would be very nice! thanks!

Comment: If the value of `stringy` should be a number to be converted into an `int`, why do you expect the user enters `"q"`. Or the other way around: if the user should enter `"q"`, why are you trying to transform it into an `int` (which will fail and throw an exception)?

Comment: Think this through logically: You read in some text, which might be a number, or might be the letter "q". Then, you try to parse it as an Integer object. But "q" isn't an integer, so what does attempting to parse it as one do?

Comment: Because i need the int value to be read later as part of the dice game. I want it to be both a string and an int....lol

Comment: By the way, **NEVER** skip handling the exception or the stacktrace, even less when you're in learning phase. The stacktrace contains a message about the exact problem that happened in the application, use `e.printStacktrace();` until you learn better options to handle exceptions like logging and sending them by email.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
do {
    try {
        System.out.println("how many times");
        stringy = scanner.next();
        if (stringy.equals("q")){
          System.exit(0);
        }
        rollnumber = Integer.parseInt(stringy);
        nigh = 2;
   }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("invalid. re-enter");
        scanner.nextLine();
   }
} while (nigh == 1);
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation to the code posted.

Answer (score 5):

It will never reach the condition that checks for "q", since it will get an exception in parseInt.

If you type "q", parseInt would throw NumberFormatException before your condition that checks for "q".

You should move your `rollnumber= Integer.parseInt(stringy);` line to be after the condition.

My suggestion (without the `System.exit()`) :

```
boolean quit = false;
do {  
 try {
    System.out.println("how many times");   
    stringy= scanner.next();                
    if (stringy.equals("q")) {
       quit = true;
    } else {
       rollnumber= Integer.parseInt(stringy);
    } 
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
    System.out.println("invalid. re-enter");
    scanner.nextLine();
 }          
} while (!quit);
```

Comment: thanks so much! I have a question though: if i parseint, does it change it to an integer completely and thats why the if statement can't be executed?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You're right, I just noticed it and fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @BoyBoy If the String can't be parsed an an integer (since it contains non numerical characters, such as `q`), it throws an exception.

Comment: @JonK It will throw an exception in this case, and then it would expect a new input to be entered.

Comment: @Eran Of course it would - that's what I get for reading it too fast!

Answer (score -2):

I think you are not going out of the while-loop when you try to exit your app. Maybe you can try and add a return statement in the if after you try to exit your app.

Comment: If you still don't have enough expertise to *compile* and *execute* code while reading it, it would be better if you test the code in your IDE and analyze it. After analyzing the problems there, provide your answer.

Comment: You haven't red the question.